# Why am I getting a type error when trying to instantiate an empty backbone.js view?

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js, instantiation, typeerror

I am in the process of learning backbone.js and have written some very simple code.

I am getting an error when executing the following line:

```
var myView = new View();
```

Here is the error in Firebug:

```
TypeError: i is not a function
```

When I comment out that line there is no error (of course... no view object either).

Here is the code:

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

        var Model        = Backbone.Model.extend({});       
        var Collection   = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
        var View         = Backbone.View.extend({});

        var myModel      = new Model();
        var myCollection = new Collection();
        var myView       = new View();

</script>
</body>
```

**My question is:**

Why do **myModel** and **myCollection** instantiate properly, but **myView** does not?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It works fine for me, do you have the correct scripts included?  Maybe you have another script that's conflicting with backbone.js?

Comment: I was missing jQuery.  Thanks for the help, Jack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing Underscore or jQuery in your HTML script references.

Backbone requires Underscore.js, and should be used with either jQuery or Zepto for DOM manipulation. Specifically with view instantiation, you need either jQuery or Zepto.

Your HTML file should include those files in the right order:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/backbone.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was missing jQuery.  I knew that underscore was a hard dependency for backbone, but didn't realize underscore needed jQuery.  Thank alot for the help, Derick.

Comment: @mozzletoff actually it isn't underscore that requires jQuery rather backbone.js [requires](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#) either jQuery or Zepto for views.

Comment: @Jack is right. it doesn't matter what order you put jQuery vs Underscore, but you must have both of them prior to Backbone, in the script list.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, guys.  Time is an issue for me right now so your help is greatly appreciated.